# In old data frame, order by two columns and store first of each row into new data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame that contains 3 columns and I'd like use the columns `date` and `location` to obtain the most recent observation of each location and store it into a new data frame.

```
> old.data
date location amount
2014 NY       1
2015 NJ       2
2016 NY       3
2015 NM       4
2013 NY       5
2014 NJ       6
2016 NM       7
2016 NJ       8
2015 NY       9

> new.data
date location amount
2016 NJ       8
2016 NM       7
2016 NY       3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

new.data <- old.data %>% arrange(desc(date), location) %>% group_by(location) %>% slice(1)

new.data

Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
Groups: location [3]

   date location
  <int>   <fctr>
1  2016       NJ
2  2016       NM
3  2016       NY
```

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
# Code updated by Arun
setDT(old.data)[order(-date, location), .(date = date[1L]), by = location]

   location date
1:       NJ 2016
2:       NM 2016
3:       NY 2016
```

**Data**

```
old.data <- structure(list(date = c(2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2015L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2015L), location = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("NJ", "NM", "NY"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("date", 
"location"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

**Update (as OP changed the original dataframe)**

The `dplyr` solution is still valid.

For `data.table`, this is the only way I could think of:

```
setDT(old.data)[order(-date, location), colnames(old.data), with = F][date == max(date)]

   date location amount  
1: 2016       NJ      8 
2: 2016       NM      7
3: 2016       NY      3
```

Using **.SD** and **.SDcols** as suggested by **Arun**

```
# adding more data
old.data$amount <- 1:9
old.data$a <- 10:18

# Retain all columns
keep_cols <- colnames(old.data)[-2] # Remove the column which is mentioned in by

setDT(old.data)[order(-date, location), .SD[1L], by = location, .SDcols = keep_cols]

# or assigning colnames to .SDcols directly: 

setDT(old.data)[order(-date, location), .SD[1L], by = location, .SDcols = (colnames(old.data)[-2])]

   location date amount  a
1:       NJ 2016      8 17
2:       NM 2016      7 16
3:       NY 2016      3 12
```

Comment: Your data.table solution is awesome. ~10X faster than the garbage I came up with.

Comment: I lied. When I ran things a couple times the answers were actually very comparable -- your solution is usually 2-3 nanoseconds faster. Both answers scale to a data.frame with 1e6 rows with very little change in performance.

Comment: How can I change the column name for date in `new.data` in the `data.table` function?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Arun! I ordered by location to match the desired output posted by OP. @Provisional.Modulation, Arun's updated code solves your problem

Comment: Modified original post to reflect increased data frame dimensions.

Comment: @Sumedh, use `.SD` with `.SDcols`.. See sections 2e and 2f in the [Getting started](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) vignette.

Comment: Perfect. Note that you can assign `colnames()...` to `.SDcols` directly as well..

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
library(dplyr)
date <- c(2014, 2015, 2016, 2015, 2013, 2014, 2016, 2016, 2015)
location <- c("NY", "NJ", "NY", "NM", "NY", "NJ", "NM", "NJ", "NY")

old.data <- data.frame(date, location)

new.data <- group_by(old.data, location)

new.data <- summarise(new.data, year = max(date))
```

Comment: you deleted one of my favorite comments :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[order(-date), .SD[1L], by = location]
#    location date
# 1:       NY 2016
# 2:       NM 2016
# 3:       NJ 2016
```

Comment: I have two questions: 1) How can I edit the `data.table` function so that I have the right column names? 2) How does this function change if the original data frame has 50 columns instead of 2?

Comment: Test out the code and see what happens -- the answer should work for a data.table of any size. You can edit the data.table names with the `setnames` function. It would be worth reading a little about the data.table package.

Comment: @Provisional.Modulation, start [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)...

Comment: @Arun Thanks, I didn't realize you were following the comments! 
Modified original post to reflect increased data frame dimensions.